# I can't find ConvexHull in scipy.spatial

Tags: python, scipy, convex-hull

> Edit: As far as I can tell it's an issue with the build, I haven't figured out exactly what yet, but I've narrowed it down to that. For anyone reading this, try the suggestion in the marked answer first.

I'm trying to use the ConvexHull function from the `scipy` library to compute the convex hull for some points, but `scipy.spatial.ConvexHull` doesn't seem to exist.

The documentation has this as an example:

```
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
points = np.random.rand(30, 2)   # 30 random points in 2-D
hull = ConvexHull(points)
```

I tried to use this example in my project but couldn't get it to work..

I typed in the appropriate import line but ConvexHull was not found, PyCharm underlined the ConvexHull reference in red, and a mouse-hover shows a 'not found' message.

I've found various mentions on SO about different methods that might be required for importing and using parts of scipy, which I've tried and none of them seem to work, including the import line in the docs example.

I'm running Python 3.6 inside a clean PyCharm venv that I've just created. The `pip` install of `scipy` worked fine and `scipy` is appearing when I try to import it, as is `spatial`... but `ConvexHull` doesn't seem to exist.

I'm using scipy 1.1.0, and I've tried using the import that a deleted answer provided...

`from scipy.spatial.qhull import ConvexHull`... but this didn't work.

Alternately, if this won't work then I am willing to use a different library if possible.

Comment: *"... but couldn't get it to work."* Please include the exact, complete error message in the question.

Comment: What's the OS?  linux?

Comment: OS is Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html

Did you try

```
from scipy import spatial
spatial.ConvexHull
```

In 1.0.1 both of these work

```
In [2]: spatial.qhull.ConvexHull?
In [3]: spatial.ConvexHull?
```

Glancing at the github issues, there may be some build issues, involving cython versions, that may prevent building the `qhull` file.

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8562 - CI: Appveyor builds fail because it can't import ConvexHull from spatial.qhull

---

I upgraded to 1.1.0, and had no problem accessing `ConvexHull`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer hpaulj, as far as I can tell it's an issue with the build.